# Prove that inequality $\sqrt{|a-b|}+\sqrt{|b-c|}+\sqrt{|c-d|}+\sqrt{|d-e|}+\sqrt{|e-a|}\le 3+\sqrt{2}$

Tags: inequality

> let $a,b,c,d,e\in [0,1]$, show that
>   $$\sqrt{|a-b|}+\sqrt{|b-c|}+\sqrt{|c-d|}+\sqrt{|d-e|}+\sqrt{|e-a|}\le 3+\sqrt{2}$$

I have tried to use AM-GM inequality, but get no result as follows:
$$(|a-b|+|b-c|+|c-d|+|d-e|+|e-a|)(1+1+1+1)\ge (\sqrt{|a-b|}+\sqrt{|b-c|}+\sqrt{|c-d|}+\sqrt{|d-e|}+\sqrt{|e-a|})^2$$

Comment: If $a=c=1$ and $b=d=0$ then $LHS=4 > 2+\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @Khue, I have somewrong before,Now I think is  Holde

Comment: Similarly for $(0,1,1/2,0,1).$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Five is an odd number, therefore the differences
$$
  b - a, c - b, d - c, e - d, a - e
$$
(when viewed as a cyclic sequence) cannot have only alternating signs.
There must be two successive differences which are both $\le 0$ or
both $\ge 0$. Therefore in 
$$
  a, b, c, d, e
$$
(also viewed as a cyclic sequence) there must be three successive
numbers which are increasing or decreasing.

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $a \le b \le c$.
It is easy to calculate that
$$
  f(x) = \sqrt{x-a} + \sqrt{c - x} \, , \, a \le x \le c
$$
attains its maximum at the midpoint $(a+c)/2$ of the interval  and therefore
$$
\sqrt{|a-b|}+\sqrt{|b-c|} = \sqrt{b-a} + \sqrt{c - b} \le 2 \sqrt{\frac{b-a}{2}} \le \sqrt 2 \, .
$$
Since
$$ \sqrt{|c-d|}+\sqrt{|d-e|}+\sqrt{|e-a|} \le 1 + 1 + 1 = 3$$
holds trivially, the conclusion follows.

---

Equality holds for
$$
(a, b, c, d, e) = (0, \frac 12, 1, 0, 1) \,
$$
so the bound $3 + \sqrt 2$ is sharp.

Comment: One question, could this be treated as a five variable function and use Lagrange multipliers to find its maximum in the region considered?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: It might be at bit cumbersome, because  the absolute value function is not differentiable everywhere. Also the example shows that the maximum is attained at the boundary of the domain. – But it may be possible of course, I was just happy that I found a solution at all :)