# Maximize value of the function $A=\sqrt{|x-y|}+\sqrt{|y-z|}+\sqrt{|z-x|}$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value, maxima-minima

Let $0\le x,y,z\le 2$. Find maximize value of the function $$A=\sqrt{|x-y|}+\sqrt{|y-z|}+\sqrt{|z-x|}$$

---

Outside $(x, y, z)=(0, 1, 2)$ and $A_{\text{max}}=2+\sqrt2$ I have no way in this problem.

Comment: So sorry, fixed

Comment: Btw, here is the corresponding question for five variables: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426664/prove-that-inequality-sqrta-b-sqrtb-c-sqrtc-d-sqrtd-e-sqrt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WLOG assume $x\le y \le z$. Then we may rewrite the function as
$$\sqrt{y-x}+\sqrt{z-y}+\sqrt{z-x}$$
It is now evident it is increasing in $z$ and decreasing in $x$, so we may set $z=2, x=0$, to get
$\sqrt y + \sqrt{2-y} +\sqrt2$ to maximise using your favourite method for univariate functions.

I would finish with Jensen ;)